# Digital Image Processing - How to determine percentage of "X" color from "Y" colored background

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, image-processing

I'm building a mobile app via React Native that requires some image processing: I need to determine the percentage of color red splotches on a green colored background. I've done some research already into some other discussions on the ImageMagick discussion archives, but I'm really lost.

There are two main things I need help with:
1. Again, devising a method to extract the percentage of color red splotches covering a green colored background (e.g., "this image is 40% covered with green")
2. How I would go about implementing such a method in my React Native project (javascript).

Image Stipulations:
1. the image will be taken via a smartphone
2. image will not have 1 red rgb value and 1 green rgb value, but rather a range of colors close to red and green on the image (this is a consequence of there will be shading on the image

If you can lead me to any old thread, a specific topic to read on, or anything that would mean the world to me!
Thanks

Comment: can you edit in some attempts you've tried? i dont see any code here. Reply here when you've done so and ill retract my vote

Comment: How about posting an example image. You can post to some free hosting service and put the link in your question. Without seeing an example, it is hard to know what to recommend for processing. One thought might be to simply get the ratio of the red channel average value to the green channel average value.

Comment: Another idea is to threshold on the range of hues that represent red and also that represent green. Then make that binary and get the two averages.